# DataList not displaying data

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

So I have a DataSource and also a DataList:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SearchDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\4WheelsDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SearchDataSource"></asp:DataList>
```

When a user clicks on a button it performs this code which amends the query according to what the user has chosen:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE "

if(make != 1)
{
   query = query + "make_id = @make";
   SearchDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("make", make.ToString());
}

SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
btn_search.Text = DataList1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

However when the datalist should show some rows the btn_search.Text displays 0 and rows are not shown in the datalist, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **where** clause in your query.

**C#**

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Cars"

if(make != 1)
{
   query = query + " where make_id = @make"; // add here
   SearchDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("make", make.ToString());
}

SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
btn_search.Text = DataList1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SearchDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblmake_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("make_id")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: You must add ItemTemplate in you DataList.I edited my answer.Try it again.

Comment: Okay I have done that and rather than `SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;` just for testing i have tried `SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Cars";` and it works, so it seems their is something wrong with the bind params, I dont understand what could be wrong with them though :/

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: It seems their is something wrong with the parameter binding

Comment: Could you accept the answer if the question of "DataList not displaying data" already done.

Comment: It's not displaying data though, its displaying data when I do a "SELECT *" but not when i do it accordingly to my inital question

Comment: I can get data by SelectParameter successfully by the code i edited above.